# getenv('REMOTE_USER) does not insert value into database log

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database that stores users' access logs.The problem is that every other specified column in the database is populated with the corresponding data,but the user_info column is empty all through. Kinda like the variable $user does not contain a value. I have been on this for a while now, everything seems right but it does not fully accomplish my purpose. Thanks for your help.
Here's the MySql code.

```
    //Database Connection
    require( 'db.php' );

/* The User Info to be gathered */

$time       = date( "M j, Y | G:i:s A" );
$user       = getenv( 'REMOTE_USER' );
$ip         = getenv( 'REMOTE_ADDR' );
$userAgent  = getenv( 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' );
$referrer   = getenv( 'HTTP_REFERER' );
$currentPage    = getenv( 'REQUEST_URI' );
$query      = getenv( 'QUERY_STRING' );

if( isset( $time, $ip, $userAgent, $referrer, $currentPage ) ) {
/* Log all the required information into the database */
    $prep = $db->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO renal_accessLog(
            ip_address,
            user_info,
            time,
            page,
            referrer,
            search,
            user_agent
        ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
        ");
    $prep->bind_param(
            'sssssss',
            $ip,
            $user,
            $time,
            $currentPage,
            $referrer,
            $query,
            $userAgent
        );
}
$prep->execute();
$prep->close();

$db->close();
```

Here's my code on the login end. To determine which user is logged in and obtain that user's information.

```
//find out who we are dealing with
        if ( true || isset($HTTP_SERVER_VARS['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
            $username = $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
//          if ($HTTP_SERVER_VARS['HTTP_HOST'] == 'example.com' && (!$HTTP_SERVER_VARS['PHP_AUTH_USER']))  {
//              // this is a little kludge for development purposes
//              // if running in locsl mode and nobody has logged in, 
//              $username = "Teresa"; // Teresa, the developer
//          }

            //look for user record, and if found, remember his model
            $myQuery = "select people.FirstName, people.LastName, modelusername, people.MDFlag, people.ContactId from users left join people on people.ContactId = users.contactId where username = '$username'";
            $result = sql($myQuery);
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $firstName = $row[0];
            $lastName = $row[1];
//          $initials = strtoupper("tm");
            $UserInitials = (substr($firstName,0,1) . substr($lastName,0,1));
            $userFullName = $firstName . ' ' . $lastName;
            if ($row[3] == 'Y') {
                $userFullName .= ", MD";
            }
            $modelusername = $row[2];
            $userId = $row[4];
            echo "<center>Hello, ". $firstName . " " . $lastName . " (" . $UserInitials . ")." ;
            if ($modelusername) {
                echo "You are authorized as '$modelusername'.  " ;
            }
```

Comment: You should be retrieving most of that from the `$_SERVER` superglobal.  `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS` is deprecated and the environment is all in `$_SERVER`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: As you have it, I believe `getenv()` returns `FALSE` for an unavailable value resulting in `false` set in your variables. `isset()` returns _true_ if the value is `false`, so your condition would still proceed.

Comment: Yes that's right. But how can I get the logged in user.

Comment: If the web server has populated `REMOTE_USER` via HTTP basic auth, it will exist in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`. Sometimes Apache (if that's what you use) will cause env vars to be rewritten during redirects or proxying as `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER']` use `var_dump($_SERVER)` to see what it contains.

Comment: i used var_dump($_SERVER) but discovered that server does not contain [REMOTE_USER]. Please you can take a look at the code above and let me know if you find anything unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
$user       = getenv( 'REMOTE_USER' );
$ip         = getenv( 'REMOTE_ADDR' );
$userAgent  = getenv( 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' );
$referrer   = getenv( 'HTTP_REFERER' );
$currentPage    = getenv( 'REQUEST_URI' );
$query      = getenv( 'QUERY_STRING' );
```

With:

```
$user       = $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'];
$ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$userAgent  = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$referrer   = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$currentPage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$query      = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Comment: I get error that says _Call to a member function execute() on a non-object_ ($prep->execute)  when i use $_SERVER. But works fine when I use getenv(); Thanks